# How to execute a program when a text file is called and still return the proper text

Tags: filesystems, version-control

The question is fairly simple. I want to create a program that would hook the VFS and run the program in order to generate or read the data that would be create. I.E.: the file itself would hold all past revisions, hashes, data, and editors of its various versions. But in a normal call to the file (ala gcc sourcefile.c, vim readme.txt the file would read/write) like a normal text file.

I figure I would have to hook the VFS to do so, and treat my file more like a 'special file' in the file system so it didn't act normally and instead calls the program in question which actually reads and outputs the files data. But I'm wondering where I would start with documentation on such a project the first several google searches and phone a friends have failed.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) (which stands for Filesystem in USErspace). FUSE is a kernel driver and associated userspace utilities and libraries which allow a userspace program (potentially unprivileged) to implement a filesystem driver. The program defines how to implement filesystem primitives (`open`, `read`, `write`, `mkdir`, etc.). FUSE is available for [most modern unix variants](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=OperatingSystems).

There are already [many existing FUSE filesystems](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems). Of particular interest to you is [copyfs](http://n0x.org/copyfs/), which keeps a history of all the successive versions of all files.

If what you want is really to keep past versions of a file, you'd be better off with a [revision control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control_system) such as CVS, git, Mercurial, etc. A revision control system not only stores successive versions of the files under its control, but also stores change comments, allows branches in the version history, lets you group multiple files together, and much more.

Answer (score 0):

> where would I start with documentation on such a project

Have a look at [avfs](http://avf.sourceforge.net/).